# How are WCF adapters and other available adapters in BizTalk server different?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2010

How are WCF receive adapters and other receive adapters in BizTalk server different?

e.g. : What basichttp adapter of WCF in BizTalk server can do, a normal BizTalk http adapter can also do and then what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to begin...

For starters, here is the documentation:

WCF-BasicHttp Adapter = http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246098.aspx

HTTP Adapter = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267545(v=bts.10).aspx

WCF in general = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

What is the basic difference is that all WCF adapters are WCF based and as such are fully extensible, configurable in all ways WCF bindings supports.
This gives you full flexibility in your connectivity. Much more than you get with the traditional adapters.

Worth mentioning as well is that WCF is off course fully compatible with the Microsoft .NET stack (since 3.5 I think) and can be used for all types of communication out of the box.
MS SQL, Oracle, BasicHttp, Siebel, ...

Also worth mentioning is that WCF fully complies to WS-* standards (where applicable) and has lots more support then custom coding anyting.

Hope this somewhat covers the tip of the iceberg about differences...

Comment: Thanx but i would like to little more about it. 1) How WCF adapters are extensible(give one liner eg if possible). @Pieter

Comment: Hi Mukesh,
Please see the following link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789051.aspx